# In Excel, how can I dynamically highlight a row based on a cell whose value is the number of the row I want to highlight?

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

In my Excel Spreadsheet, I have a table set up and want to be able to dynamically hightlight the table row that corresponds to the value in a cell.

For example, let's say my table spans cells `A1:M13`

Then, outside my table in, say, cell `e17` (any cell outside the table), if I enter the number `4`, I want all of row 4 in my table highlighted.

I know that I would need to configure Conditional Formatting, and create a `New Rule...`, and `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`. But, I'm having a hard time figuring out a formula to use.

I'm playing around with the `ROW()` and `INDIRECT()` functions, but not getting there.

Comment: Is it really necessary to enter the row number in _any_ cell outside the table? You could have one defined cell e.g. A1 (highlightRow) (moving the table two rows down), name it, highlight it by a background color - and then use that value for the format condition: sth like `= ROW() = highlightRow + 4`

Comment: certainly there would be one specific cell. Didn't mean to indicate that I could just select any cell anywhere on the sheet.

Comment: That said, your solution works. I didn't need the +4 at the end. Submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have one defined cell e.g. A1 (highlightRow) (moving the table two rows down), name it, highlight it by a background color - and then use that value for the format condition: sth like
`= ROW() = highlightRow + 4`